# REGEX: \d not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text:

`Wheels – F/R_ Schwalbe TABLE TOP/Schwalbe Black Jack 26x2.2`

And **regex** to parse wheels size from that string:

```
/.*Wheels.*(\d*)x/
```

But it does not work. Besides, when i'm removing asterisk from **regex**, i'm getting number `6` as group match.

Comment: `.*Wheels.*?(\d*)x`

Comment: @PavneetSingh , working, but could you please explain where was my mistake and format that as an answer, so i can accept it.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to select 'Wheels' from the string and nothing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your regex non-greedy because `.*` will consume your digits and `\d*` mean zero or no match

```
.*Wheels.*?(\d*)x
```

`.*?` mean match as many characters as few time as possible to stop `.*` to consume your digits

[`Follow this Demo for example`](https://regex101.com/r/DX3HoR/1)

---

Alternately you can make it more efficient if there are no digits after  `Wheel` and your desired values with following regex

[`.*Wheels[^\d]*(\d*)x`](https://regex101.com/r/fZFmcY/1)

where `[^\d]*` mean matches anything except digits

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @Src i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 4):

You need to make your `.*` before the digits [*lazy* instead of *greedy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions):

```
/.*Wheels.*?(\d*)x/
```

The `.*` will greedily consume everything up to the `x`, leaving nothing for the following `\d*`. Since `*` can validly match zero characters, an empty match for `\d*` is not an incorrect result.

By adding a `?` to make a lazy `.*?` expression, it will try match as few characters as possible, allowing the following `\d*` to match all the numbers before the `x`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Wow great explanation, I finally understand what lazy means in regex!